# Hide and footer when side bar opens jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide my footer when i click on menu, because it opens a side bar, however when i click on menu to close the sidebar the footer will not show again
The code below hides the footer, but does not show the footer when same event happens

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#js-footer-hide').click(function () {
            if ($('.canvas-slid').length < 0) {
                $('footer').show();
            } else {
                $('footer').hide();
            }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: Hi @mosinskis can you add your html code as well?

Comment: Hiding an element doesn't remove it from the DOM so the `length` will still be `1` or more, hence your `if` logic will never enter the `else`

Comment: i think you meant `if ($('.canvas-slid').length > 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking the `$('.canvas-slid').length` you need to check is `.canvas-slid` is visible or not with [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
$(function() {
    $('#js-footer-hide').click(function() {
        if ($('.canvas-slid').is(":visible")) {
            $('footer').show();
        } else {
            $('footer').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks kiran.  That worked, but I had to change the class I was targeting.